# How to export the Certificate details related to the particular IIS site using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, ssl, certificate, iis

I have written the below code to export only the one server's SSL certificate details related to the IIS sites, but I want the script to run for multiple servers. How do I fix this issue?

```powershell
Import-Module -Name WebAdministration

#Number of days to look for expiring certificates
$threshold = 300

#Set deadline date
$deadline = (Get-Date).AddDays($threshold)

Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:SSLBindings | ForEach-Object -Process
{
  if ($_.Sites)
  {
    $certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:LocalMachine/My |
      Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -EQ -Value $_.Thumbprint

      [PsCustomObject]@{
      ServerName                = $env:COMPUTERNAME
      Sites                     = $_.Sites.Value
      CertificateIssuer         = $certificate.Issuer
      CertificateSubject        = $certificate.Subject
      CertificateDnsNameList    = $certificate.DnsNameList
      CertificateNotBefore      = $certificate.NotBefore
      CertificateNotAfter       = $certificate.NotAfter

      #CertificateExpiryInDays      = New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End $PSitem.NotAfter.Days
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How can i get it done for multiple servers, please help me

Comment: Is there an error? Can you just run this on another server? Do you mean you want to run this remotely on another machine from a single machine? Please clarify

Comment: From a single machine i need to run this

Comment: should be able to use invoke command like this `Invoke-Command -FilePath "c:\temp\getSSLCert.ps1" -ComputerName server1,server2,server3`